# How to calculate maximal square size when fitting N squares in a given container?

Tags: integer-programming

Given a container which width is `W` and height is `H`, I'd like to fit `N` squares of maximal size `S` in it.

## Example 1

```
W = 240
H = 210
N = 7
S = 70
```

[image]

## Example 2

```
W = 200
H = 230
N = 23
S = 40
```

[image]

How would you calculate `S` from `W`, `H`, and `N` in `O(1)`?

Comment: Do the squares have to be axis aligned?  That makes it much easier

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes!

Comment: Does the original rectangle always have integer dimensions, and do the squares need to have an integer side length?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $W \ge H$ (otherwise swap them).  If you could pack them perfectly the area would say $S=\sqrt{\frac {WH}N}$.  If you use that side you get $m=\lfloor \frac HS \rfloor$ across the height.
Start with $m+3$ (just a guess for safety) across the height, compute
Side that fits in height $\frac H{m+3}$
Number required in width $n=\lceil\frac N{m+3}\rceil$
Side that fits in width $\frac Wn$
Now decrease the number across the height and recompute the sides
It should increase and then start to decrease.  Report the maximum.

Comment: It this an `O(1)` solution? How many checks we need to perform in the worst case before we can stop?

Comment: I don't really know.  I'm not sure $3$ is enough margin.  Probably it is better to start at $\frac Hm$ and go both ways until you see a decrease.  I haven't figured out a way to bound how many tries you have to make.